# Unity can I instantiate a game object from a scriptable object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

I want each bow to shoot a different arrow that I set in the SO when it is created. I need each bow to shoot the assigned arrow prefab in the SO.

WeaponConfig has `[SerializeField] public GameObject projectile;` field where I want to be able to swap out different arrows so each new weapon can shoot different arrows that I will set in the inspector.

Shoot Script:

```
    public void ShootingArrows()
    {
        var screenCam = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        Vector3 worldMousePos = screenCam;

        // Direction of mouse to player
        Vector2 direction = (Vector2)((worldMousePos - firePoint.position));
        direction.Normalize();

        // Creates the arrow locally
        GameObject arrow = (GameObject)Instantiate (
                                arrowPrefab,
                                firePoint.position + (Vector3)( direction * 0.5f),
                                firePoint.rotation);

        FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("BowShoot");
        
        // Adds velocity to the arrow
        arrow.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = direction * arrowForce;

        // Rotate arrow based on position from player to cursor
        angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        arrow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward), 1000 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

In my Instantiate I have `arrowPrefab` called that is set as a game object at the top of the script.

What do I change this to, to instantiate the intended projectile?

If I change it to this code below then it is saying it does not have an object reference.

```
     GameObject arrow = (GameObject)Instantiate (
                             WeaponConfig.projectile,
                             firePoint.position + (Vector3)( direction * 0.5f),
                             firePoint.rotation);
```

I have the Projectile slot in the inspector filled in with the intended arrow I want shot. Each one has a different prefab selected. How do I instantiate the assigned arrow in the SO?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well instead of the so far

```
public GameObject arrowPrefab;
```

you would need to have a

```
public WeaponConfig config:
```

field, reference your `Bow` asset there and then do

```
GameObject arrow = Instantiate (
                         config.projectile,
                         firePoint.position + (Vector3)(direction * 0.5f),
                         firePoint.rotation);
```

Comment: That is what I had earlier but the config.projectile then complains about Object reference not set to an instance of an object. How do I assign the projectile to the instance?

Comment: That sounds like you didn't reference your `Bow` asset into the `config` field then. Otherwise `Instantiate(null)` would throw a different exception ;)

Comment: Yep! Finally found it, I never added a reference to my WeaponConfig in my ShootingArrows function.